# How to use Hyperledger fabric for existing cryptocurrency trade (Ether, Bitcoin)?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ethereum, bitcoin

I am working on a project for creating a platform which specializes on cryptocurrency trading. I want to migrate from Ethereum blockchain to Hyperledger fabric. My question is can I use Hyperledger fabric for existing cryptocurrency trade transactions, e.g. Ethereum, Bitcoin and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger fabric does not have native cryptocurrency support.Though you can always include bitcoin api([bitcoin for developers](https://bitcoin.org/en/bitcoin-for-developers)) with your contract. But hyperledger fabric being private/consortium kind of Blockchain I don't know what exactly you are looking out for.